# VS code intellisense for includes doesn't work for header files when using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, intellisense

`c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
...
{
    "name": "CMake",
    "compileCommands": "${config:cmake.buildDirectory}/compile_commands.json",
    "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
}
...
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
add_executable(main source/main.cpp source/foo.cpp [and the rest])
...
```

Intellisense is able to find all the includes for my `cpp` files since these are being compiled by CMake and so have entries in the `compile_commands.json` file. However, my header files are not compiled and so don't have entries and, because of this, intellisense complains about the includes in those header files.

The two solutions I see are:

- Allowing VS code to look elsewhere for includes for files not in the `compile_commands.json`. I tried adding `includePath` to `c_cpp_properties.json` but this doesn't work since VS code only looks in the `compile_commands.json` file even with this option specified.
- Adding the header files to the `compile_commands.json` file. I am not sure how to do this though since I don't actually want to compile the header files.

Comment: Compiling header files as standalone translation units is a good practice, it helps you to keep headers self-contained and avoid introducing unexpected relations between them. Since you have to compile that code many times already (as in, in every `#include`), I don't suppose adding them to compile list would add much to compilation time.

Comment: Have you tried adding the headers to the executable in cmake, it won't affect the compilation but might fix intellisense